# How can I call JavaScript function after the whole web page loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, onload-event

I have JavaScript function , I want to run this function when webpage is completely loaded, But it's not working.
here is my code

```
window.onload = function() {
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
          <div> <button class= "btn">
                <img src="logo.png" height="20px" width="70px">
             </button>
          </div>
        `);
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally, it should work! Maybe there is not any element with the "title" class name. You could set a breakpoint and check it.

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean by *It's not working*? The function is not called? Your code is not doing anything?

Comment: actually it's worked on other sites but when I want to run on naukri.com it's not worked.

Comment: Firstly make sure this function run or not by adding a breakpoint or console.log() before the `var btn...`; And check if there is any other onload event in your code.

Comment: basically I want to add extra html element on naukri.com site's job card through my JavaScript function, it's added but when page is fully loaded then hide this element.

Comment: see the `console` for any other errors

Comment: It's worked sometime , I have to refresh webpage again and again.